# Why am I receiving 'ValueError: This model has not yet been built'? [Following tutorial]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am following this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/text_generation on SLES 15. I get the below error when I run my code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ml2.py", line 107, in <module>
    model.summary()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2521, in summary
    raise ValueError('This model has not yet been built. '
ValueError: This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling `build()` or calling `fit()` with some data, or specify an `input_shape` argument in the first layer(s) for automatic build.
```

The weird part is, it somehow worked before without me calling build or fit. I searched through the tutorial and it doesn't mention anything about build or fit or input_shape. What did I mess up that it stopped working?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing

import numpy as np
import os
import time
path_to_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file('namefile.txt', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/redrover9/nameGenerator/master/fakeNames.txt')
# Read, then decode for py2 compat.
text = open(path_to_file, 'rb').read().decode(encoding='utf-8')
# length of text is the number of characters in it
print(f'Length of text: {len(text)} characters')
# Take a look at the first 250 characters in text
print(text[:250])
# The unique characters in the file
vocab = sorted(set(text))
print(f'{len(vocab)} unique characters')
example_texts = ['abcdefg', 'xyz']

chars = tf.strings.unicode_split(example_texts, input_encoding='UTF-8')
chars
ids_from_chars = preprocessing.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=list(vocab), mask_token=None)
ids = ids_from_chars(chars)
ids
chars_from_ids = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=ids_from_chars.get_vocabulary(), invert=True, mask_token=None)
chars = chars_from_ids(ids)
chars
tf.strings.reduce_join(chars, axis=-1).numpy()
def text_from_ids(ids):
  return tf.strings.reduce_join(chars_from_ids(ids), axis=-1)
all_ids = ids_from_chars(tf.strings.unicode_split(text, 'UTF-8'))
all_ids
ids_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(all_ids)
for ids in ids_dataset.take(10):
    print(chars_from_ids(ids).numpy().decode('utf-8'))
seq_length = 100
examples_per_epoch = len(text)//(seq_length+1)
sequences = ids_dataset.batch(seq_length+1, drop_remainder=True)

for seq in sequences.take(1):
    print(chars_from_ids(seq))
for seq in sequences.take(5):
    print(text_from_ids(seq).numpy())
def split_input_target(sequence):
    input_text = sequence[:-1]
    target_text = sequence[1:]
    return input_text, target_text
split_input_target(list("Tensorflow"))
dataset = sequences.map(split_input_target)
for input_example, target_example in dataset.take(1):
    print("Input :", text_from_ids(input_example).numpy())
    print("Target:", text_from_ids(target_example).numpy())
# Batch size
BATCH_SIZE = 64

# Buffer size to shuffle the dataset
# (TF data is designed to work with possibly infinite sequences,
# so it doesn't attempt to shuffle the entire sequence in memory. Instead,
# it maintains a buffer in which it shuffles elements).
BUFFER_SIZE = 10000

dataset = (
    dataset
    .shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
    .batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
    .prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE))

dataset
# Length of the vocabulary in chars
vocab_size = len(vocab)

# The embedding dimension
embedding_dim = 256

# Number of RNN units
rnn_units = 1024
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units):
    super().__init__(self)
    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
    self.gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(rnn_units,
                                   return_sequences=True,
                                   return_state=True)
    self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)

  def call(self, inputs, states=None, return_state=False, training=False):
    x = inputs
    x = self.embedding(x, training=training)
    if states is None:
      states = self.gru.get_initial_state(x)
    x, states = self.gru(x, initial_state=states, training=training)
    x = self.dense(x, training=training)

    if return_state:
      return x, states
    else:
      return x
model = MyModel(
    # Be sure the vocabulary size matches the `StringLookup` layers.
    vocab_size=len(ids_from_chars.get_vocabulary()),
    embedding_dim=embedding_dim,
    rnn_units=rnn_units)
for input_example_batch, target_example_batch in dataset.take(1):
    example_batch_predictions = model(input_example_batch)
    print(example_batch_predictions.shape, "# (batch_size, sequence_length, vocab_size)")

model.summary()
```

Comment: In your own words, exactly what do you think is different between your code and the verbatim code from the tutorial? Are you able to make that code work? What happens when you try gradually adding your changes?

Comment: At this point I am copying the verbatim code from the tutorial. The only difference between that code and my code is I left off the part after it started erroring out. Even if I add that code I get the same error. So to answer your question, nothing, no, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you trying this code at the interpreter prompt, or in a file? If it's in a file,then lines like `chars` do nothing, and you can omit them (or if you want to see the values, explicitly `print(repr(chars))` etc.). If you're using the interpreter prompt, do you see the results you expect from all of these lines?

Comment: I found the linked duplicate by putting `keras this model has not been built yet` into a search engine. In the future, please try steps like that first. It [is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).